# How to check if text message has actually been sent?

Tags: iphone, sms

On my iOS 14.5.1 iPhone 7 how can I check if an SMS message has actually been sent or not?

It is just a green bubble with no sent confirmation nor 'pending' indication anywhere near it in the Messages app. I don't trust my 1-0 bar fluctuating network connection.

How can I find out if the message has been sent or not?

Comment: Press on message, hold and swipe left to see timestamp? I don’t know whether it’s operator based but if my SMS is not sent it is accompanied with red circle with exclamation mark.

Comment: @AivarPaalberg that happens for me only as soon as sending fails, in the obvious case of having no network connection at all for exampl. I don't know how to distinguish between sent and pending.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SMS Message doesn't state it has been sent](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/62872/sms-message-doesnt-state-it-has-been-sent) especially this answer https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/62874/237 (SMS is not a reliable transport)